# SQL NULL constraint on UPDATE only

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, constraints

Is there a way to have a constraint on a column in a table that doesn't allow NULLS on UPDATES? Null still should be allowed on insert.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

no, you have to deal with the logic separately with a trigger or any other mechanism

Comment: hmmm. The problem is my ERP system that sits on top of the database will only display constraint error messages, but not trigger error messages.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an onupdate trigger? you are using transactions (tsql) so this should be a possible solution. as far as i know check constraints can't be limited to e.g. update queries.

Comment: Yes. The problem is my ERP system that sits on top the database will only display constraint error messages, but not trigger error messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark the column as `NOT NULL`.
2. Add a `DEFAULT` value.
3. Create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger  to replace inserted nulls
   with the default value.

This should meet all the requirements.

---

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
    ClientId int, 
    OptionalOnInsert int NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    Field1 int, 
    Field2 int
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Client_InsteadOfInsert ON Client
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT Client (ClientId, OptionalOnInsert, Field1, Field2)
    SELECT ClientId, OptionalOnInsert, Field1, Field2
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE OptionalOnInsert is not null

    INSERT Client (ClientId, Field1, Field2)
    SELECT ClientId, Field1, Field2
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE OptionalOnInsert is null
GO

-- Inserting NULL succeeds
INSERT Client (ClientId, OptionalOnInsert)
VALUES (1, NULL)

-- Updating to NULL fails
UPDATE Client
SET OptionalOnInsert = NULL
WHERE ClientId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing a trigger that would check on update to see if the field is NULL.